# Returning Folder path of a file in google drive

Tags: java, class, google-drive-api, filepath

Am trying to return and fetch the folder path of a Google drive file. The inputs am passing is
input:
folder id, file name and oauth token.

{
"id":"1dVkHw5442B7wMidj",
"name": "Path"
}

The class which am using below:

```
 public static  List<File>  Search(Object payload,String oauthToken) {
       List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>(); 
       List<File> subfolderlist = new ArrayList<File>(); 
       List<File> subQuerylist = new ArrayList<File>();
       GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential(); 
       credential.setAccessToken(oauthToken);
       try {
            _driveService = new Drive.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential).setApplicationName(appName).build();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
       try {
           String filename ="";String mimeType ="";
           String modifiedFrom ="";String modifiedTo ="";String fullText ="";
           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
           String jsonString =null;  String paramquery ="";  
            jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString); 
            String parentId = jsonObject.getString("id");
            if(!jsonObject.isNull("name")){
             filename = jsonObject.getString("name");
             paramquery +=" and ( name contains '" + filename + "' or  fullText  contains   '" + filename  + "')";
            }
            if(!jsonObject.isNull("content")){
                fullText  = jsonObject.getString("content");
                 paramquery +=" and  fullText  contains   '" + fullText  + "'";
            }
            if(!jsonObject.isNull("mimeType")){
                mimeType = jsonObject.getString("mimeType");
                if(mimeType.equals("AllFiles") ){
                 paramquery +=" and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"; 
                }else {
                 paramquery +=" and  mimeType =  '" + mimeType + "'";
                }
            }
            if(!jsonObject.isNull("modifiedFrom")){
                modifiedFrom = jsonObject.getString("modifiedFrom");
                 paramquery +=" and modifiedTime >   '" + modifiedFrom + "'";
            }
            if(!jsonObject.isNull("modifiedTo")){
                modifiedTo = jsonObject.getString("modifiedTo");
                 paramquery +=" and  modifiedTime <   '" + modifiedTo + "'";
            }
            
            String subfolderquery = " and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"; 
            subfolderlist = ExecQuery(_driveService,subfolderquery,parentId); 
             list = ExecQuery(_driveService,paramquery,parentId); 
             int i = 0;
             while (i < subfolderlist.size()) {
                 File file = subfolderlist.get(i);
                 subQuerylist = ExecQuery(_driveService,subfolderquery,file.getId());
                 if(!subQuerylist.isEmpty()) {
                     subfolderlist.addAll(subQuerylist);
                 } 
                 i++;
             }
             
             int j = 0;
             while (j < subfolderlist.size()) {
                 File file = subfolderlist.get(j);
                 subQuerylist = ExecQuery(_driveService,paramquery,file.getId());
                 if(!subQuerylist.isEmpty()) {
                     list.addAll(subQuerylist);
                 } 
                 j++;
             }
           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return list; 
    }
```

But it returns me only the file details and parent folder id.

How can i retrieve the complete path of the file?

Answer (score 0):

### Drive files and folders do not have paths

They do have parents, but the parent is property rather than the location of a file. Paths assumed by following the nesting of folders and subfolders are of imaginative nature.

The reason a Google Drive file cannot have a path is that you can have two different files of diferent mimeType with the same name in the same folder. Also as of now (will be deprecated in the future) a file can have simultaneously multiple parents.

The closest thing you can do to understand the nesting hierarchy of files in subfolders is to iteratively loop through parent of the parent of a file until you get to the `root` - "My Drive".